# How to create a anonymous android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential for google endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

web client: https://gcl-11.appspot.com/

source code: https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/blob/master/android/src/my/endpoints/EndpointsActivity.java

This example is using google endpoints with android. I managed to get it to work, except it is mandatory also for non authenticated requests to first login before I can reach the server without a `bad username` error. In the webclient it's not.

about:

```
EndpointsClient.Builder endpoints = new EndpointsClient.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential);
```

question:

Is it possible to use a anonymous android client for non user object api request in google endpoints? I tried to set a empty account name but then I get `bad username`?

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, AUDIENCE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName("");
```

If not, can I specify a default one without using `getSelectedAccountName()`?

Also why does this not return a user email like the webclient?

```
Message response = service.post("greetings/authed", null).setOauthToken(token).execute();
```

Comment: When you say "anonymous" do you mean you don't want the client to authenticate?

Comment: Only if the server needs a user object like I did for the web client. It seems that I need to setup a credential in android for all api request and a extra oauth2 token for the server user object that I did not manage to get working yet when android is making the api request.

Comment: Is this calling https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/blob/master/appengine/rs/src/main/java/rest1/Greetings.java ? If so, you'll get a NPE unless you pass a valid user object. I think the behavior you are seeing in Android is working as intended and the bigger question is why your web client is working if you don't authenticate.

Comment: As you can see for non user api requests in https://gcl-11.appspot.com/ it does :)

Comment: If I hit the authed greeting endpoint without signing in it returns "undefined". Sure, the other API calls will work (they don't require authentication). You don't need to pass a credentials object to `EndpointsClient.Builder` if you are making requests to unauthenticated APIs.

Comment: True, but why on android do I need to select a credential account "gert.cuykens@gmail.com" for all non authentications too for example https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://gcl-11.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/rest1/0/rest1.greetings.listGreeting? It does not work otherwise if "" is specified instead or not set at `EndpointsClient.Builder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discusion with Dan Holevoet above I tried a longshot and replaced the `GoogleAccountCredential credential` with `HttpRequestInitializer noCredential` and that suddenly worked for non authenticated request.

EDIT:
`credential = null;` also works.

Comment: If you put the credential to null, you are just making a generic call and there is no authentication.